# Batch insert in oracle using max(column) + 1 for primark key gives DuplicateException error

Tags: java, oracle, sql-insert, batch-insert

I was trying to do batch insert in oracle DB. The query being:

```
INSERT INTO <table-name> (A, B) values ((SELECT MAX(A)+ 1 FROM <>table-name), "xyz")
```

There were similar two statements in the batch insert. The above operation threw DuplicateException.

Comment: Now you know one reason why generating IDs in this manner is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a sequence or computed (generated) column for calculating A -- although Oracle has historically made that more difficult than it should be.

However, if your problem is with `A`, then problem may be that `A` is always `NULL`.  If so:

```
INSERT INTO <table-name> (A, B) 
     SELECT COALESCE(MAX(A), 0) + 1, 'xyz'
     FROM <table-name>;
```

You might also have a unique index/constraint on `B` or on some other column not included in the `insert`.  And, for completeness, I should mention that the error could be coming from an insert trigger on the table.

Comment: No. `A` is not `NULLL`

Comment: Another possibility is two inserts at the same time, which conflict.

Comment: My question is: Will the batch insert will cause any problem?